# AggCat Account Data - Time required to refresh

Tags: aggregation, intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

I am using the Intuit AggCat Beta in a development environment and noticed that when I discover new accounts, they often don't include important information like balances, current interest rates, and other key pieces of data. This is true even after calling functions like getAccountTransactions or getCustomerAccounts (not simply discoverAndAddNewAccounts).

However, after a few hours, I refresh the accounts and this information shows up. It's very important that new accounts include this data during the discovery process, and I wanted to check if this is an issue of using the development environment (e.g. something that will go away in production?) or if other users are having this issue

Answer (score 3):

This is how it works in both dev and prod environment. During the account discovering, it may not be able to get all information for some accounts for some financial institutions because of their website layout/data limitation.

The refresh call will get these information. So the best practice is to refresh the account before you try to get these information.